# EOFY age based on date of birth

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an age based on the end of the financial year.
If my date of birth is the 16th Jan 1962 my current age is 50 (assuming today's date is the 16th Jan 2012). What javascript formula/function could I use to calculate the age at the end of the current financial year (ie. 30th June 2012)?

This is what I have to get the current age:

```
function getAge(dateString) { 
    var today = new Date(); 
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString); 
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear(); 
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth(); 

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) { 
        age--; 
    } 

    alert("current age "+age) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the end of the current financial year as the "today" date, right? And then the end of the current financial year would either be hardcoded into the function, or figured out programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to calculate the difference between two dates:

```
function ageAtEOFY(birthDate) {
    var eofy = new Date("2012-06-30");
    var msDiff = eofy - new Date(birthDate);
    return Math.floor(msDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25);
}
```

Used like this:

```
ageAtEOFY("1962-01-16"); // 50
ageAtEOFY("1984-11-14"); // 27
```

The way this works is that `eofy - new Date(birthDate)` gives you the difference between the two dates in milliseconds. The rest is just converting that value into years.

Note that there's a bit of a fudge here: leap years [don't simply occur every four years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).